# Can I use CMU Sphinx in a php based e-shopping CMS?

Tags: php, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I want to integrate a speech recognition system for search in a e-Shopping system based on a CMS. This CMS is made in Php. So does CMU Sphinx support Php integration?
Or is there any other way of doing the task?

Comment: How exactly do you plan to use it? Can you provide more details? What sort of speech recognition do you need? Do you need to provide users the control over the website or do you need to be able to upload some files and transcribe them. Or do you need something else?

Comment: I want the user to be able to navigate various products based on voice commands. eg. He'll say a product name to display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(repurposing an old answer from a similar question...) Is your goal is to do speech recognition from an html page? Chrome supports speech recognition for text input. See http://slides.html5rocks.com/#speech-input and http://www.filosophy.org/2011/03/talking-to-the-web-the-basics-of-html5-speech-input/.

These use the following tag for speech recognition:

```
<input type=”text” speech x-webkit-speech />
```

I believe Chrome is the only browser that currently supports this. http://tomlerendu.com/tutorial/how-to-use-html-5-speech-input/ has a good example and shows

```
if( document.createElement('input').webkitSpeech==undefined )
{
  //no speech support
}
```

as a means to test if speech recognition is supported.

Historically, there have been other approaches. Opera implemented a different solution, but it appears they are no longer supporting it - http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/getting-to-know-voice/.

Another approach that has been used is to use a java applet or flash app that communicates with a speech recognition back end. WAMI is a good example of this - http://wami.csail.mit.edu/. These approaches use a rich client (Java or Flash or other plug in) to capture speech and send it to a server or some local speech engine for processing.